# How to put space before page number in Table of Contents in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I want to put some space before page numbers in Table of Contents in MS Word.
I aligned the page numbers to the right. But couldn't put space after leaders, before page numbers. What I want to do is something like this:

[image: Table of Contents]

Answer (score 0):

you need to add another TAB in the definition of the format that is used there.
When you click in that line, you will see the style in the ribbon that belongs to it (probably TOC1, unless you changed it).

Right click that style and chose 'Modify'. Add a tab in the position where you want the leader dots to stop. The leaders are a setting at the tab, so the tab you placed will be able to contain 'no leaders', and the space from where you place it to the numbers will be blank.

Save this as a change to the style, and all the lines will have your new look.